# Don't know how to solve this error

Tags: python, csv, row

I am reading a CSV file, editing some of the values in it, and trying to write a CSV file. But when I try to execute it says the stuff in the imgur link. I'm not sure why it is doing this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph7Ee.jpg

Here is the Excel/CSV file:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=45E225BF1E0ACB4%21606)

```
import csv

f = open('project survey.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

def encoder(x):

    for row in csv_f:
        if row[2] == "2018":
            row[2] = 1.0
        elif row[2] == "2017":
            row[2] = 2.0
        elif row[2] == "2016":
            row[2] = 3.0

        print (row)         
    return row  


new_data = []
for row in encoder(csv_f):
   new_data.append(row)

print (new_data)

f = open('new_data.csv','wb')

output = csv.writer(f)

for row in new_data:

    output.writerow([row])
```

Comment: Will you please add traceback to this question ? also give output of `print (row)`

Comment: Your `encoder` function doesn't return anything. Therefore, `new_data` is a list containing a single element, `None`. You should notice that when you print it. And why does your `encoder` function have a parameter if you're not using it?

Comment: @Carsten I replaced "print" with "return" and removed the argument from encoder(x) and it changed the entire output to this: http://imgur.com/FAwVcqk

Comment: The "traceback" to which @Lafada refers is the part of your output that starts with the word `Traceback`... **Stop posting pictures**: your code, data and output are all text and shoupd be included in the question formatted as such. If there's too much, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, you have a colossal amount of repetition. Why not make a dictionary of what should be e.g. `1.0` for each column? And why do `if x == 'foo': ... elif x != 'foo': ...`?  That's just `else`!

Comment: Yea you are right I am sorry about that. I have reduced the code above. The error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

writerow is for writing a sequence(lists or tuples) to file not single variable.
You have given a single value 'row' as parameter to writerow which should be a sequence actually.

try

```
for row in new_data:
   output.writerow([row])
```

or

```
  output.writerow(new_data)
```

Comment: This is really interesting but trying both, I get http://imgur.com/TFPuCag,xYsEvAt http://imgur.com/TFPuCag,xYsEvAt#1

Comment: @JohnChen The problem I believe is because your function is returning None instead of returning row. add return row after the print(row).

Comment: when I add a return row, it gives me this http://imgur.com/ZaMY8Ka which is weird because I don't understand why it only gives me a shortened output

Comment: Put return outside the 'for' loops indentation.Like below
        print (row)  
    return row and while writing to file write as  output.writer([row])

Comment: If return row is outside the for loops, wouldnt it just return the last row though? I've done what you told me and this is what happens: http://imgur.com/wP0n2qq

Answer (score -1):

With all of your help, I've finally figured out how to fix this.

Here is the new code:

```
import csv
f = open('project survey.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

new_data = []

def encoder(x):
    for row in csv_f:
        if row[24] == "Other":
             row[24] = 1.0
        elif row[24] != "Other":
             row[24] = 0
        new_data.append(row)
    return new_data

encoder(csv_f)
print(new_data)

f = open('new_data.csv','wt')
output = csv.writer(f)

for row in new_data:
    output.writerow(row)

f.close()
```

in order to return and not print I had to create a new empty list to append everything to.

At first it wasn't writing to new_data.csv because python 3 needs you to specify encoding. Luckily, simply putting "wt" next to "new_data.csv" allows you to save as text instead of binary.

Thanks a lot everyone this has been really educational.